# Pyqtgraph: How do I update the X-Axis values without it moving

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

So I have found this code that creates a python graph that is updated a plot in real time that does everything i need, but i would like if instead of the x-axis moving the values are updated. I have been searching for examples but i only find a static version where the values of the x values stay the same.

What i have right now:

[image]

what i want:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
# Create Plot Widget
self.scrolling_timestamp_plot_widget = pg.PlotWidget(axisItems={'bottom': TimeAxisItem(orientation='bottom')})

# Enable/disable plot squeeze (Fixed axis movement)
self.scrolling_timestamp_plot_widget.plotItem.setMouseEnabled(x=False, y=False)

self.scrolling_timestamp_plot_widget.setTitle('Signal 1 ')
self.scrolling_timestamp_plot_widget.setLabel('left', 'Value')
self.scrolling_timestamp_plot_widget.setLabel('bottom', 'Time (s)')


self.scrolling_timestamp_plot = self.scrolling_timestamp_plot_widget.plot()

self.scrolling_timestamp_plot.setPen("r")
```

```
def plot_updater(self):
    self.data_point = float(self.current_position_value)

    self.data.append({'x': self.timestamp.elapsed(), 'y': self.data_point })

    print("List Values:",self.data)
    self.scrolling_timestamp_plot.setData(x=[item['x'] for item in self.data], y=[item['y'] for item in self.data])
```